# Need help in getting HTML of a website in Java

Tags: java, html, httpurlconnection

I got some code from [java httpurlconnection cutting off html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285077/java-httpurlconnection-cutting-off-html) and I am pretty much the same code to fetch html from websites in Java. 
Except for one particular website that I am unable to make this code work with:

I am trying to get HTML from this website:

> http://www.geni.com/genealogy/people/William-Jefferson-Blythe-Clinton/6000000001961474289

But I keep getting junk characters. Although it works very well with any other website like http://www.google.com.

And this is the code that I am using:

```
public static String PrintHTML(){
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.geni.com/genealogy/people/William-Jefferson-Blythe-Clinton/6000000001961474289");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100625 Firefox/3.6.6");
    try {
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n"); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String html = builder.toString();
    System.out.println("HTML " + html);
    return html;
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work with the URL that I mentioned above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That site is incorrectly gzipping the response regardless of the client's capabilities. Normally a server should only gzip the response whenever the client supports it (by [`Accept-Encoding: gzip`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3)). You need to ungzip it using [`GZIPInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html).

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream()), "UTF-8"));
```

Note that I also added the right charset to the `InputStreamReader` constructor. Normally you'd like to extract it from the [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header of the response.

For more hints, see also [How to use URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) If all what you after all want is parsing/extracting information from the HTML, then I strongly recommend to use a [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281) like Jsoup instead.

Comment: Wow it worked. Thanks for the explanation. And a big thanks for the snippet as well.
I initially tried using HTMLCleaner as my parser, but I was getting the same issue. Now I am going to feed this HTML string into HTMLCleaner.

Comment: BTW, jsoup (1.3.1) now deals with that gzipped output correctly when using `Jsoup.connect(url).get();`